Cases where a misunderstanding in mathematics led to misunderstanding of the physcis?
Quite some time ago, Anthony Zee asked the following question during a KITP coffee break. Namely, are there any cases where misunderstanding the mathematics led to a misunderstanding the physics? I came up with one example, concerning the Schwarzschild metric. Before the Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates were discovered, the nature of the horizon was not properly understood. From the Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates, it is clear that one can cross the horizon, without noticing anything special, at least at first.
Are there any other examples where a misunderstanding of the mathematics led to a misunderstanding of the physics?

Maybe this question is best suited for History of science and mathematics SE.

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. Does miscalculation count? In this example, Einstein initially miscalculated a prediction of GR as matching that of earlier physics due to Newton, only for it to be later realized GR actually doubles the prediction, which is what a subsequent experiment verified.

I'm not entirely sure Zee is someone who would ask that question in good faith, without redefining terms such that any concept that turns out to be important is somehow "physics" and "math" only is used to describe things that are somehow "trivial". I also think the question is unfair because it leaves out many examples students have where they have difficulties in physics because of misunderstanding math (there are many examples on this site), as well as examples where researchers get stuck on a mathematical issue and then probably don't talk about it once they resolve it.

But another example could be the initial dismissal of Yang-Mills by people like Pauli, where it wasn't understood that the spectrum derived in perturbation theory need not hold non-perturbatively. And if Zee would try to call that "physics" rather than "math", I'd say (a) why not both, and (b) this very issue is a Millennium prize problem in mathematics.

@Mauricio, thanks for the suggestion. I'll post there if I don't get any answers here...

@eddyardonne if you wish you are allowed to have it in both sites, as long as you indicate that it is a duplicate

@J.G. while miscalculations can be interesting, I'm looking for more fundamental 'mistakes'.

@Andrew it is of course important to identify which struggles students have, but I'm interested in knowing cases where the physics community was led astray because of a misunderstanding in mathematics

@Mauricio, thanks,  I'll certainly mention the question here if I crosspost on History of science and mathematics

My bigger point is that you need to predefine what you would consider "a misunderstanding of mathematics" vs "a misunderstanding in physics" before you can hope to get reasonable answers to this question. I think it would be extremely easy to move the goalposts to reinterpret mistakes as "mathematical" or "physical" depending on the answer you want to get if you aren't very clear up front what you mean by those terms.

In the all-important 1927 Solvay conference (and now the proceedings are published with commentary as Quantum at the Crossroads), there was a discussion of some calculation in quantum theory that ended up being a dud, coming from a mathematical mistake. It was so involved that nobody in the conference was able to catch it, so much so that it ended up in the conference proceedings as unsolved. It cast a bit of a doubt on some physics for a while. Also, the many infinities arising in QFT also cast decades worth of doubt on QFT as a whole, until Lamb shift showed a path towards renormalisation.

A huge roadblock in QED occurred because of technical, mathematical issue in terms of how to renormalize divergent integrals. I think you could define this as mathematical or physical depending on your point of view.

@Andrew, I'll think more about what I mean by 'misunderstanding in mathematics' vs 'misunderstanding in physics' and edit the question accordingly, when/if I think I came up with something that is less ambiguous.

What does "KITP coffee break" mean? Is it related to https://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/outreach/cafe-kitp ?

As it was closed, maybe is time to post it at HSMSE which is more sympathetic to big list category.

@Mauricio, I now posted the question on HSMSE, https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/18027

@PM 2Ring, I meant a normal coffee break at the Kavli Institute for theoretical physics (Santa Barbara, as you correctly identified), so not during one of the outreach 'cafe-kitp' events.
